# Dropdown bind to generic list

Tags: asp.net, generics, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'd like to bind my dropdown to a generic list.

It seems really simple but I keep getting the error `DataBinding: 'InternalPurchasingForms.Types.Item' does not contain a property with the name 'itemID'.`

Here's my code for the class:

```
namespace InternalPurchasingForms.Types
{
  public class Item
  {
    public int itemID;
    public String name;
    //...
  }
}
```

Here's my dropdown databinding code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        { 
        List<Item> allItems = DataAccessLayer.getAllItems();
        uxDropDownItemList.DataSource = allItems;
        uxDropDownItemList.DataValueField = "itemID";
        uxDropDownItemList.DataTextField = "name";
        uxDropDownItemList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I want to tell the dropdown that the "value" for each line is Item.itemID and that the "text" is Item.Name, but ASP.NET's telling me that those fields don't exist inside Item. I'm able to access Item's fields just fine elsewhere.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: do u have a page called Item ?

Comment: No, I have a class called `Item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using a getter and setter in your Item class for itemID and name.

Comment: Aha! Thanks buddy, this was it. (And you answered first)

Answer (score 1):

I am setting properties in this way and its working fine while binding with dropdown.

```
 private int _itemid= 0;
 private string _name = "";
 public string name
 {
   set { _name = value; }
   get { return _name ; }
 }
 public int itemID
 {
   set { _itemid= value; }
   get { return _itemid; }
 }
```